# Ecuacion cuadratica en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Me podrían ayudar en esto, tal vez sea muy fácil, pero me atoré desde hace 2 días y no he podido avanzar.

Solo me falta poner la condición `si (b**2)-(4ac) = 0` entonces pasar directamente a `-b/(2*a)` e imprimirlo y sacar la gráfica de la función

```
#Crear una función para resolver una ecuación cuadrática.
# a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0
# a, b, c
def discriminante(a, b, c):
    discrim = (b**2)-(4*a*c)
    return discrim

def sdiscrimin():
  discrim 
  return

def raices(a, b, discrim):
  #raiz1=(-b + sqrt(discrim))/(2*a)
  #raiz2=(-b - sqrt(discrim))/(2*a)
  raiz1=(-b + (discrim**.5))/(2*a)
  raiz2=(-b - (discrim**.5))/(2*a)
  cero = -b/(2*a)
  return raiz1,raiz2,cero

    enter code here

print('Calculo de raices')
a=float(input('a: '))
b=float(input('b: '))
c=float(input('c: '))
disc=discriminante(a,b,c)

if disc < 0:
  print("No hay raices positivas")

elif sdiscrimin == 0:
  print('Solo existe una raiz')
  print(raices(cero))
  
else:
  print("La raices son: ")    
  print(raices(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Para la parte del discriminate estabas llamando de forma incorrecta a tu funcion, además la función `sdiscrim`, no entiendo honestamente que objetivo tenia asi que la borre. Además tenias un `---Enter code---` que supongo estaba de más.

Para la graficación use la libreria de `MatplotLib` en un rango de -100 a 100, sin embargo lo puedes ajustar.

Por favor lee el código cuidadosamente, en caso de haber algo que no entiendas no dudes en preguntar:

```
#Crear una función para resolver una ecuación cuadrática.
# a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0
# a, b, c
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def discriminante(a, b, c):
    discrim = (b**2)-(4*a*c)
    return discrim

#def sdiscrimin():
#    discrim 
#    return
def f(a,b,c,x):
    return a*(x**2) + b*x + c
    

def raices(a, b, discrim):
    #raiz1=(-b + sqrt(discrim))/(2*a)
    #raiz2=(-b - sqrt(discrim))/(2*a)
    if disc < 0:
        pass
    elif disc == 0:
        cero = -b/(2*a)
        return cero
    else:
        raiz1 = (-b + (discrim**.5))/(2*a)
        raiz2 = (-b - (discrim**.5))/(2*a)
        return raiz1,raiz2
    




print('--------------Calculo de raices------------------')
a=float(input('a: '))
b=float(input('b: '))
c=float(input('c: '))

#Discriminante
disc=discriminante(a,b,c)

#Grafica
x = range(-100,100)
pyplot.plot(x, [f(a,b,c,i) for i in x])
#Color de los Ejes
pyplot.axhline(0, color="black")
pyplot.axvline(0, color="black")
#Limite de los ejes
pyplot.xlim(-100, 100)
pyplot.ylim(-100, 100)
#Mostrar grafico
pyplot.show()

if disc < 0:
  print("No hay raices positivas")

elif disc == 0:
  print('Solo existe una raiz')
  print(raices(a,b,disc))
  
  
else:
  print("La raices son: ")    
  print(raices(a,b,disc))
```

Espero que te sirva. ¡Saludos!